# Technology vs Business site category

Tags: discussion

Currently [Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/) and [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) are both categorized as [technology sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology)

[Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) is categorized as a [business site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#business)

I can see the rational for both categories. How can we compare the relative advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: In my eyes Bitcoin is also a technology site, however, the category really does not matter as the community can decide from within what's the site about.

Answer (score 6):

I like the Technology category we are in now. A comment from Murch to your same question on the Bitcoin meta led me to this discussion of the very issue from when the Bitcoin site was first launched:

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/business-or-technology